# SQL Error Invalid

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select pet_id, name, type, breed, gender from pet
where gender ='F' or gender ='X'
and where name like '%S'
order by gender;
```

The code returns an error stating ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: `where gender ='F' or gender ='X' and name like '%S'`

Comment: you don't need the second `where`

Comment: the code now works but only returns some of the expected results.The question is                                                                                     
                                                                                                     
Produce a list of pets whose name starts with or ends with the letter ‘s’. Exclude all
male pets from the list. Display the pet’s id together with its name, type, breed and
gender.

Comment: Your query only takes care of the case where the name ends with a capital s. You haven't checked for the names starting with an s (and you should use the upper() or lower() function on the name column to make the check case insensitive.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT pet_id
    ,NAME
    ,type
    ,breed
    ,gender
FROM pet
WHERE gender IN ('F', 'X')
    AND NAME LIKE '%S'
ORDER BY gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pet_id,
  name,
  type,
  breed,
  gender
FROM pet
WHERE gender in ('F','X')
---Where remove and from here
and name LIKE '%S'
ORDER BY gender;
```

Comment: This will error as you have two `WHERE`'s in your statement. You don't want to remove the `AND` you want to remove the `WHERE`